# Microsoft ML Onnx Runtime cannot find library

Tags: c++, onnx, onnxruntime

I tried to use the library : Package Microsoft.ML.OnnxRuntime -Version 1.10.0 (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ML.OnnxRuntime) for my very first ONNX C++ project. I use Visual Studio 2019.
I have no clue how to link "Install-Package Microsoft.ML.OnnxRuntime -Version 1.10.0" (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ML.OnnxRuntime) to my Visual Studio 2019.  I got error "Cannot find Linear.h".

Comment: Please read the [description](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ml/info) of the ML tag.

Comment: What do you mean by "link"? Do you mean how to install the package? Check out this sample console app for c++ from my github, that might help https://github.com/cassiebreviu/cpp-onnxruntime-resnet-console-app there is a video on how to use c++ and onnx runtime on the youtube channel as well https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=imjqRdsm2Qw